# Why does entering Select * from dual; crash my login-page (a self security-test )?

Tags: mysql, security, stress-testing

I have a [simple PHP/MySQL login page](http://abdussalam.info/muhammad/login/login.php) that I want to security-test . when I enter in

```
Select * from dual;
```

into the username-field , then it crashes it.

I'll get this error  :

```
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

But  when I tried entering in the simple ``` `` ``` that went through fine? why is this ?

Comment: How about showing the actual source code and we can tell you whether it’s vulnerable?

Comment: @Gumbo - Ok, I'll get it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information to determine what the problem is. But this is the kind of behavior we'd expect if your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  If you are including data from the POST into SQL text, without properly "escaping" the values to make them safe, or better yet, using prepared statements with bind placeholders.